# UIBarButtonItem created programmatically not Tapping and linked

Tags: ios, swift

I created a view controller for a UIBarButtonItem, a toggle on the main controller. but the UIAction button is inactive

```
import UIKit

class SideMenuContentViewController: UIViewController {
    //Manipulation for Dashboard Side Menu Hamburger
    let profileButton = UIButton(type: .custom)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        profileButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "hamburger") , for: .normal)
        profileButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        profileButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // function performed when the button is tapped
        profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(profileButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        // Add the profile button as the left bar button of the navigation bar
        let barbutton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileButton)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barbutton

        // Set the width and height for the profile button
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profileButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0),
            profileButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35.0)
        ])

        // Make the profile button become circular
        profileButton.layer.cornerRadius = 35.0 / 2
        profileButton.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    @IBAction func profileButtonTapped(_ sender: Any){

    }
}


import UIKit

class MainSideViewController: SideMenuContentViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var dashBoardViewLeadingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var sideMenuVisible = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 - self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width
    }

    @objc func toggleSideMenu(fromViewController: SideMenuContentViewController) {
        if(sideMenuVisible){
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                // hide the side menu to the left
                self.sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0 - self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width
                // move the content view (tab bar controller) to original position
                self.dashBoardViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        } else {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                // move the side menu to the right to show it
                self.sideMenuViewLeadingConstraint.constant = 0
                // move the content view (tab bar controller) to the right
                self.dashBoardViewLeadingConstraint.constant = self.sideMenuContainer.frame.size.width
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }

        sideMenuVisible = !sideMenuVisible
    }
}

    // THIS IS THE ACTION NOT WORKING

    @IBAction override func profileButtonTapped(_ sender: Any){
        if let mainVC = self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.parent as? MainSideViewController {
            mainVC.toggleSideMenu(fromViewController: self)
        }
    }
}
```

I want the action to google in the side menu.

Comment: Did you mean to have two `profileButtonTapped` functions in your question? The first is empty and the second is outside of either class. Maybe you should fix the formatting to make it clear.

Comment: I have two. One in the SideMenuController I intend to use in the views and the second one is in the view where I want to tap it

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Yes it's in a controller I'm using for my content. Should it be in the MaInSideViewController?

Comment: I moved the second profileButtonTapped method inside the MaInSideViewController class and its working

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Thanks a lot it worked! but the action inside to toggle is not working